# How to stop Senna.js from calling multiple jQuery event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, senna.js

I have developed a SPA website using Senna.js and it works great! However, I have recently noticed that it doesn't remove jQuery event handlers when leaving the page. So I have all kinds of functions firing twice when I navigate back to a page I have already visited.

[image]

I fixed most of my personal code by doing this

`$("#element").off("event").on("event", etc.)`

But there are thousands of lines of other people's code which is also powering my website and I am worried that they are firing twice as well.

Does anybody on SO have any insight or approaches to handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detach event handlers using Senna's lifecycle events. For example:

```js
var app = new senna.App();

app.on('beforeNavigate', function() {
// detach jQuery event handlers
});
```